# Can AI help summarize article or abstract sentence keyword?

Tags: natural-language-processing, artificial-neuron

I'm wondering if AI now can help us abstract summary or general idea of long article, for example novel or historical stories, or abstract most important keyword from sentence;

Would you please tell me if any of this kind of project is done?

I wish I can improve my reading speed and effectiveness with AI help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Text summarisation has been a research topic in (computational) linguistics for literally decades. Have a look at the [Wikipedia page on Automatic Summarisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization) for an overview.

There are basically various different approaches: either, selecting salient sentences (or parts of sentences) which represent the gist of the text, or, trying to 'understand' the text and generating new sentences. The former is generally easier, and works on any text, while the latter would probably be able to produce better results, but is more complicated and would not work on any text, as it would be specific to a particular topic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It would be great if there's any available service on internet for text summarisation, what I need is just copy and paste article in text input, and it will return summarize result to me, then I can improve my reading speed soon

Comment: @gloomyson [smmry](https://smmry.com/) is reasonably popular, and sounds similar to what you request.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to dear Oliver Mason's answer

You can check [here](https://github.com/topics/text-summarizer) to see how people uses machine learning tools to summarize texts and also check some articles from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/tagged/text-summarization) to understand its background If you are curious about.